# convert array to hash to extract wanted columns perl

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, multiple-columns

I have an array (obtained from a match with two lists), it is a list of lines with different columns similar to (in this case i just use 3 columns of values "numbers" ) :

I have tried :

```
my %row;
@row{@match_all} = split "\t";
```

and

```
foreach ( @match_all ){
        my %row;
        @row{@sample_names} = split "\t";
        my @filter= join "\t", @row{@wanted};  
          push (@wanted_columns, @filter); #



$VAR1 = {
'#Genera' => 'namex',
'sample1' => '0.0024',
'sample2' => '0.0013',
'sample3' => '0.0'
};
```

Comment: The first code block is not valid code. Please show us what `@match_all` contains.

Answer (score -1):

```
use strict;
use warnings qw( all );
use feature qw( say );

sub get_row {
   my ($fh) = @_;
   my $line = <$fh>;
   return undef if !defined($line);

   chomp($line);
   return [ split(/\t/, $line, -1) ];
}

sub get_row_hr {
   my ($fh, $headers) = @_;
   my $line = <$fh>;
   return undef if !defined($line);

   chomp($line);
   my %row;
   @row{@$headers} = split(/\t/, $line, -1);
   return \%row;
}

{
   my @wanted_cols = ( '#Genera', 'sample1', 'sample3' );

   my $fh = \*DATA;

   my $headers = get_row($fh)
      or die("Premature EOF\n");

   say join "\t", @wanted_cols;
   while (my $row = get_row_hr($fh, $headers)) {
      say join "\t", @$row{@wanted_cols};
   }
}

__DATA__
#Genera sample1 sample2 sample3
Gordonia    0.3 0.1 0.4
Mycobacterium   0.0032  0.23    0.0
Ornithinimicrobium  0.06    0.0 0.0
Pseudomonas 0.3 0.28    0.52
Halomonas   0.0006  0.1 0.1
Acinetobacter   0.9 0.02    0.5
Bacillus    0.4 0.5 0.1
Klebsiella  0.22    0.4 0.3
Lactobacillus   0.4 0.0 0.0
```

Comment: Please post an explanation with code blocks. Raw code dumps are generally not helpful to future viewers.

Comment: @Silvio Mayolo, I wrote the code to be self-explanatory. I don't know what I could add without repeating myself. There's no magic key here; just a series of simple statements. If there's something specific you think needs elaboration, please specify what and I'll elaborate. Until then, you're comment is as useless as you accuse my answer of being.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo "_Raw code dumps are generally not helpful_" -- I disagree, doubly: (1) Correct and well-written code _must be_ helpful to anyone who is willing to put in some work. In fact, it is _the_ first thing that is helpful; explanations are fine and dandy but good code is king. (2) This is not  "_raw code dump"_, it is a well written and clear program. Note that it relies on elementary features, of any language. It is also particularly suitable for the ambiguity in the question.